# Configuring iptables for Haproxy

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, router, haproxy

Ubuntu machine running haproxy with 2 network cards, 1 connected to WAN (called wan0) and another connected to LAN (called lan0). All chains set to DROP traffic.

```
# Masquerade traffic from LAN to WAN
-A POSTROUTING -o wan0 -s 192.168.x.x/24 -j MASQUERADE

# Allow traffic from LAN to WAN
iptables -I FORWARD -i lan0 -o wan0 -j ACCEPT

# Allow HTTP traffic in/out both interfaces
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT

*** Is below rule needed? ***
# -A FORWARD -i wan0 -o lan0 -p tcp –dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

I want to allow HTTP (port 80) traffic from WAN into the LAN where haproxy will route it to backend servers. Documentation I've read states:

> "INPUT, FORWARD, and OUTPUT are separate. A packet will only hit one of the three chains."

Am I missing any iptable rules that would route HTTP (port 80) traffic between interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you have the default chain policy set to `DROP`. So, you need to have explicitly `ACCEPT` rule for each type of traffic you want to allow.

The following rule will allow traffic passing through your box coming from `lan0` interface and going out of interface `wan0`.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i lan0 -o wan0 -j ACCEPT
```

Also, it is a good idea to allow other types of traffic like RELATED, and ESTABLISHED using a rule like:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This is needed to allow the response traffic to go through. You do similarly for `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains.

It really depends on your needs and what you want to allow and deny.

As for the sentence:

> "INPUT, FORWARD, and OUTPUT are separate. A packet will only hit one
>   of the three chains."

Yes, this is true. A packet will hit:

1. `INPUT` chain when it is destined to local machine.
2. `OUTPUT` chain when it is originated from local machine.
3. `FORWARD` chain otherwise (received from another machine and need to be forwarded to some other machine).